# Stuck when using IF and Concat inside a MySql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to use `IF` along with other code inside `MySql` `stored procedure` and things don't seem to be going right and I cannot save the stored procedure. If I remove the `IF` things work ok and I'm able to save the stored procedure.

The problem is with the `IF` in there. Can you help?

**Error**

```
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) THEN
                'Grey Link'
            ELSE
                SET ret_val = 'Blue' at line 20 */
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
BEGIN

DECLARE vals VARCHAR(2400);
DECLARE ret_val VARCHAR(2400);

select group_concat(elmAction) into vals from reports where id = this_id and userId = this_user;

SET ret_val = CASE this_id
    WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT (
        'Blue Type 1'
        'Blue Type 2'
        'Blue Type 3' #Here is where the problem is...
            IF FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) THEN
                'Grey Link'
            ELSE
                'Blue link'
            END IF;
        )
ELSE 'Error'
END;


RETURN (ret_val);

END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
CONCAT (
        'Blue Type 1',
        'Blue Type 2',
        'Blue Type 3',
        IF( FIND_IN_SET (10,vals), 'Grey Link','Blue link')
)
```

With `CASE` :

```
CONCAT (
        'Blue Type 1',
        'Blue Type 2',
        'Blue Type 3',
        CASE
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) = 0 THEN 'Blue link'
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) = 1 THEN ....
            WHEN FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) = 2 THEN ....
        ELSE
            ...
        END
)
```

Comment: This works, but the only problem now is you've changed the if syntax, which does not allow me to add more `elseif`

Comment: @Norman the use `CASE` statement like suggested by `juergen d`

Answer (score 1):

Use a case

```
    SET ret_val = CASE this_id
    WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT (
        'Blue Type 1',
        'Blue Type 2',
        'Blue Type 3', 
            case when FIND_IN_SET (10,vals) THEN
                'Grey Link'
            ELSE
                'Blue link'
            END
        )
```